# Delphi: GridPanelLayout ColumnCollection error

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm working on a simple (Delphi 10.1, FireMonkey) application that includes a GridPanelLayout component, 2 rows, 5 columns, each cell has a TGlyph component. The last thing I did yesterday was adjust the margins for both the GridPanelLayout and Glyphs. Everything seemed OK; I compiled and ran on Windows and OS X. I honestly can't remember whether I tried the app on Android or not at that point! In any case, I saved everything, committed to Git, and called it a day.

This morning, opening the same project I got

> Error reading GridPanelLayout1.ColumnCollection: Cannot delete a
>   column that contains controls. Ignore the error and continue? NOTE:
>   Ignoring the error may cause components to be deleted or property
>   values to be lost.

Clicking "Ignore All" generates

> Error creating form: Stream read error.

If I click OK, the app compiles and runs fine on Windows.

The same process on Mac OS X, however, generates

> Exception EReadError in module ... Error reading
>   GridPanelLayout1.ColumnCollection: Cannot delete a column that
>   contains controls.

I can't trying compiling the app for Android right now, but a google search led me to try simply switching the view to `Style: Android`, `View: Android 5" Phone`, generating the error

> View "LgXhdpiPh" already exists in module.

Switching the view to `Style: OSX`, `View: OS X Desktop` generates

> View "Macintosh" already exists in module.

And I checked the form's dfm code (i.e., Alt-F12); I see the the same 5 columns, 2 rows, and Glyphs assigned to cells as expected.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: There should be several DFM files. One master file and the subclasses for each platform. You should also check them for modifications.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful, I don't see other DFM files, though I do see FMX files. I do see some differences in how they describe the GridPanelLayout. The main form list the component, columns, rows, and links between glyph components and cells. The other FMX files don't all include all that info.